# Running Exe File from CMD using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am trying to run a cmd line from VBA. The command line calls a createReport.exe which creates a final CSV output file using Inputfile.csv

This is what I run manually from Command prompt window:

> cd C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder (hits enter)
>
> createReport.exe
> -in=C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\Inputfile.csv (hits enter)

When I run manually, it takes around 45 seconds to create final CSV output file.

When I run the same thing from VBA code, the screen says "starting the query step" and it stays on for 30 seconds, closes and doesn't create the final CSV output file.

```vb
Sub RunReport()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim strProgramName As String
Dim strArgument As String    
    
    strProgramName = "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\createReport.exe"
    strArgument = "-in=C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\Inputfile.csv"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbMaximizedFocus)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you first need to do a `ChDir` before calling the `Shell()` command, something like:

```
ChDir "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder"
Call Shell("""" & strProgramName ...
```

Comment: So, will it be something like this ? 

    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String    
    
   ChDir "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder"

    strProgramName = "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\createReport.exe"
    strArgument = "-in=C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\Inputfile.csv"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbMaximizedFocus)

Comment: No, there's no `chDir` in your code.

Comment: That is so awesome. Thanks Dominique. I added exactly what you said and it spit out the output csv. This was my first time using VBA for cmd line. It worked now. 

    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim strArgument As String    
    
   

    strProgramName = "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\createReport.exe"
    strArgument = "-in=C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder\Inputfile.csv"

    ChDir "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\MyReport_folder"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbMaximizedFocus)